# Two network routers on the same IP

Tags: networking, router, ip, arp

I have a network with several routers serving as accesspoint connected trough a switch to a central DLS/router/AP.

One of the slave router have been somehow partially reset (SSID changed to 'default' but DHCP disabled which is not by default), and now have the default 192.168.1.1 address which collide with the master router's one.
I would like to access the device and reconfigure this router but unfortunately I can only access to the network thought remote desktop on a machine connected either to the central or to the failing router.
Remote controlling this machine I discovered the conflict (the central router being reachable and the other not) and the two MAC address (arping) but I am not sure how I can solve this.

I can't access the failing router as this only respond on his default address which is obscured by the master(DHCP) and at the same time I cannot change the arp entry of computer from the central to the rouge router as this link is required for remote session to work.

The only solution I can see is changing the master router ip but I was looking for something different as this would require me a great deal of work.

Comment: What is stopping you from temporarily disconnecting the failing router from the other one and configuring it?

Comment: I am not physically there, I can only remote control a machine connected to the router. Disconnecting the failing router to the central would bring the remote session down.

Comment: Well there is nothing you can do to solve an IP conflict without changing an IP. So change the master router or get to the other router.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install a virtual machine running some form of Linux on the machine you have remote access to. In the virtual machine, hard code the ARP for `192.168.1.1` to the MAC address of the router you need to program. That should allow you to use the VM to connect to the router.

A similar solution is to log into another machine on the same local network as the machine you can remote into. On that machine, hard code the ARP entry for `192.168.1.1` to the MAC address of the router you need to program. You should still be able to access that machine from the machine you can remote into even though it won't be able to reach the Internet. Make sure to remove the ARP entry when you are done. Use a non-critical machine.

Comment: Great idea! I was thinking something like a new virtual interface and hard code its arp entry and than route the browser traffic trough this, but I am not sure how to do it. your idea seems way easier, therefore probably better!
Thank you